# Parse the data from JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, ios7

I just worried to parse the JSON data as below format. Here I need to parse userId as string or integer.

```
(
        {
        Response = success;
        UserId = 214;
    }
)
```

In my previous workout data is fetching like this `(  214   )`.

Comment: it's not JSON. http://json.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its coming like (214), why don't you try doing substring on it. Performing substring will remove the starting and ending braces. Try something like this.

```
NSString *badStr = @"(214)";
NSString *goodStr = [badStr substringFromIndex:1];
NSString *finalStr = [goodStr substringToIndex:[goodStr length]-1];
```

This will help you get the exact 214 value without the braces.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey @alwayswannalearn ur answer is good but i need assign userid value  in below code  

userId = [jsonDict1 valueForKey:@"UserId"];

Comment: Using the above code, you will get userId = (214). Then in the next step, you can do what I answered above. Else, you might have to check into your JSON because JSON strings should start with [ or {. In one of my apps, I had to go with the substring approach.

Comment: You can go with below code
userId = [[jsonDict1 valueForKey:@"UserId"] intValue];